# ngRouter no redirecciona a la ruta especificada

Tags: angularjs, ui.router

Estoy aprendiendo [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) 1.5.2 para crear mi sitio y me encuentro con un problema.

Estoy usando [ui.router](/questions/tagged/ui.router) para crear las rutas en mis páginas, *aunque solo tengo una*. Quiero que cuando los usuarios escriban la dirección, digamos: `http://localhost:3000/` se redireccione a la página `/home`.

Para lograr esto, uso al mismo tiempo `ngroute`, pero no está haciendo bien su trabajo.

Esta es la configuración de mi ruta:

```
// /app/core/rutas.config.js
(function(){
  'use strict';
  rutasConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$routeProvider'];

  function rutasConfig($stateProvider, $routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});

    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: '/app/partials/core/_core.home.html',
        controller: 'PolicyHomeController',
        controllerAs: 'phc'
      });
  }

  angular.module('cmi')
    .config(rutasConfig);
})();
```

Cuando escribo (o visito) la dirección `http://localhost:3000/#/home` todo funciona como se espera.

### Problema

`ngRoute` no redirecciona a la página especificada `/home` cuando se encuentra en una ruta diferente, tal como se indica en la línea:

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
```

¿Cuál es mi error y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

*Gracias por su tiempo*.

Comment: Creo que esta de mas a mi parecer ese redirecTo, deja te muestro un ejemplo

Comment: Yo no uso el `otherwise` para redireccionar al home sino a una página 404 o "No encontrado". Desafortunadamente eso implica que debo usar un truco para hacer el redirect. Es más código pero mejor arquitectura.

Answer (score 2):

En mi caso utilizo **ionic** para el desarrollo d aplicaciones móviles híbridas, el cual esta basado en angular; de paso recomiendan usar el **ionicbundle.js**, el cual es como una especie de paquete que reune todas las librerias que utiliza `ionic`, `angular`, `angular-ui`, entre otras, espero te sirva.

Y lo mas importante, `otherwise` no usa `{redirectTo:"ruta"}` sino solamente el string con la ruta, por ejemplo:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");

$stateProvider


    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: "Templates/login.html",
        controller: "formulario"
    });
```

Comment: Buena alternativa, ¿a qué módulo pertenece '$urlRouterProvider'?

Comment: @toledano yo estoy usando ionic, y por defecto trae integrado ui.router

Comment: hey Pedro, falto la prosa hermano :) así no te puedo votar, no explicas nada-...

Comment: @toledano listo dejame, le pongo prosa y te aviso

Comment: @toledano ya esta la prosa maestro

Comment: Pense que hibas a poner que otherwise no usa `{redirectTo:"ruta"}` sino solamente el string con la ruta.

Comment: @rnd tienes razon, si no que me inspire con eso de la prosa